# Passing configs and envfiles to pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, pytest, dotenv

Here is my project structure

```
project/
  |
  |-- pytest.ini
  |
  |-- tests/test_class.py
  |
  |-- configs/config.yml
  |
  |--app/
      |
      |-- .env
      |
      |-- class_i_want_to_test.py
```

Where `.env` file is like:

```
PATH_TO_CONFIG="../configs/config.yml"
```

Right now my `pytest.ini` looks like this:

```
[pytest]
env =
    PATH_TO_CONFIG="configs/config.yml"
```

When i am trying to pass `app/.env` file to  `pytest.ini` i am getting `FileNotFoundError`, because it can't find *'../configs/config.yml'*, so I want to change it to *'configs/config.yml'* during tests. How can i do it?

If it is not possible how should i change the project structure to be able to pass `.env` file to `pytest.ini`?